# Using PostGIS to break up large polygon into smaller segments

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a large complicated polygon that looks like this:

[image]

I want to brake this up into many smaller segments no more than about 100x100 meters in size each. How can do this? I have tried st_segmentize(target_geometry, 100) But that doesn't seem to break this up.

Comment: The functin st_segmentize is to add more (redundant) points. Seems that you need a 100x100 grid. You can use [ST_SquareGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SquareGrid.html) or ST_HexagonGrid, them create a "mosaic" by **ST_Intersection(your_multiplolygon,your_grid)**, is it?

Answer (score 7):

ST_Subdivide is a good option.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html

ST_Subdivide(geometry geom, integer max_vertices=256);

It works off vertices. So, no output polygon will have more than the specified number of vertices.

```
SELECT row_number() OVER() As rn, f.*
    FROM (SELECT OTHER_COLUMNS_HERE, ST_SubDivide(target_geometry,256) from YOUR_TABLE) AS f;
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in a comment, you can create a grid and intersect with your polygons:

```
WITH grid AS (
SELECT (ST_SquareGrid(100, geom)).*
FROM public.buff
)
  SELECT row_number() over() as id, st_intersection(grid.geom, b.geom) as geom
  FROM grid
  join public.buff b
  on st_intersects(b.geom, grid.geom)
```

[image]